# GitLab asks for password on clone via ssh

Tags: ssh, git, gitlab

I have set up GitLab via docker, as explained here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/
I then created a user and uploaded my public ssh keys using the gitlab web interface. If I connect to gitlab using ssh it works:

```
ssh -p 722 git@192.168.1.10
```

However, if I try to clone a repository

```
git clone git@192.168.1.10:722/username/sampleproj.git
```

it asks me for a password for the git user. As you can see, my ssh is not on port 22 but 722. Any advice would be welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to add ssh:// in front. This works:

```
git clone ssh://git@192.168.1.10:722/username/sampleproj.git
```